# Value Error: not in list in Code (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've tried googling and random things to see what's going wrong. Anyway I wrote this code originally importing 1 Excel file, but need it to run for every file in a folder and spit out individual file reports done in the code. I'm really trying to figure this out instead of running individual.

Error I am getting:

**ValueError: 'Has OE Intr' is not in list**

AND each time I run it, it returns a different string name as not in the list.

*I'm not real sure the best way to post sample data from a .xlsx file without it looking like data puke. If anyone has advice let me know and I'll post a sample of the data.*

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir('C:/Users/PCTR261010/Desktop/PartReviewExport')
FileList = glob.glob('*.xlsx')

# Prints header information in Part Scorecard

for fname in FileList:
    # Prints header information in Part Scorecard
    df = pd.read_excel(fname, header=None, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1)
    header = df.head(5).filter([0, 2], axis=1)


    # Begins Data Analysis of Part Scorecard
    fields = ['HQ Line', 'Part No', 'Part Class', 'Appl Req', 'Appl Count ', 'Intr Req', 'Intr Count ', 'OE Intr Req',
              'Has OE Intr', 'Has Attr Editor', ' Has Attr Values', 'Part IMG Req', 'Has Part IMG', 'Has MPCC',
              'Warr Req', 'Has Warr TXT', 'Has Warr PDF', 'MSDS Req', 'Has MSDS', 'UPC Req', 'Has UPC', 'Has UNSPSC',
              'Attr Count ', 'AttrVal Count ', 'Valid Part']

    df = pd.read_excel(fname, skipinitialspace=True,
                       skiprows=7, usecols=fields, dtype=str)



data = dict()

# Number requiring
data['valid_parts'] = len(df['Valid Part'].str.count('YES'))
data['app_req'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Appl Req'] == 'YES')])
data['intr_req'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Intr Req'] == 'YES')])
data['oe_intr_req'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['OE Intr Req'] == 'YES')])
data['mpcc'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Has MPCC'] == 'YES')])
data['part_img_req'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Part IMG Req'] == 'YES')])
data['upc'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Part IMG Req'] == 'YES')])
data['warranties'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Warr Req'] == 'YES')])
data['msds'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['MSDS Req'] == 'YES')])

# Number missing
data['missing_appl'] = len(df[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Appl Req'] == 'YES') & (df['Appl Count '] == 0)])
data['missing_intr'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Intr Req'] == 'YES') & (df['Intr Count '] == 0)])
data['missing_oe_intr'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['OE Intr Req'] == 'YES') &
                                     (df['Has OE Intr'] == 0)])
data['missing_mpcc'] = len(df[((df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Has MPCC'] == 'NO'))])
data['missing_attributes'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Has Attr Editor'] == 'NO')])
data['missing_images'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Part IMG Req'] == 'YES') &
                                 (df['Has Part IMG'] == 'NO')])
data['missing_upc'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['UPC Req'] == 'YES') & (df['Has UPC'] == 'NO')])
data['missing_warr_txt'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Warr Req'] == 'YES') &
                                  (df['Has Warr TXT'] == 'NO')])
data['missing_warr_pdf'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Warr Req'] == 'YES') &
                                  (df['Has Warr PDF'] == 'NO')])
data['missing_unspsc'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['Has UNSPSC'] == 'NO')])
data['missing_msds'] = len(df.loc[(df['Valid Part'] == 'YES') & (df['MSDS Req'] == 'YES') & (df['Has MSDS'] == 'NO')])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(data.items()))

custom_sort = {
    'valid_parts':0,
    'app_req': 1,
    'intr_req': 2,
    'oe_intr_req': 3,
    'mpcc': 4,
    'part_img_req': 5,
    'upc': 6,
    'warranties': 7,
    'msds': 8,
    'missing_appl': 9,
    'missing_intr': 10,
    'missing_oe_intr': 11,
    'missing_mpcc': 12,
    'missing_attributes': 13,
    'missing_images': 14,
    'missing_upc': 15,
    'missing_warr_txt': 16,
    'missing_warr_pdf': 17,
    'missing_unspsc': 18,
    'missing_msds': 19,
}

df2['rank'] = df2[0].map(custom_sort)

df2.sort_values(by=[0, 'rank'],inplace=True)
df2.drop(labels=['rank'],axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This is my current existing code for exporting the report to Excel. Granted I realize this will not work with importing multiple files.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname +'_Part_Report_Card.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
header.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='fname', index=False, header=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='fname', startrow=7, startcol=0, index=False, header=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['GAT']
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'gray'})
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:B5', {'type': 'text',
                                       'criteria': 'containing',
                                       'value': '*',
                                       'format': format1})
worksheet.set_column('A:B', 40)
writer.save()
```

Original Import Code for the single file code:

[image]

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  Also, can you post just the part of the xlsx file that contains 'Has OE Intr' (for instance, is it at the start of the file?  Are there other strings from the xlsx it can read?)

Comment: Each time I run it is brings back a different string in the Fields= list

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  Python should tell you the line number.

Comment: line 23, in <module>
    skiprows=7, usecols=fields, dtype=str)

Comment: I know you guys don't like images, so I'm not sure out to post the sample data file

Comment: The documentation for read_excel doesn't have the arguments you are passing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Are you using a different version, and if so, can you include a link to that version.

Comment: df = pd.read_excel('GAT_US_PartReview_2017-06-23.xlsx', header=None, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1)
header = df.head(5).filter([0,2], axis=1)

Comment: @SeeDerekEngineer ^^^ import in original code written for the single file and worked fine.

Comment: Then something is up with your excel files and how your code is interacting with it.  I'd recommend being as general as possible with your arguments in read_excel, then getting more and more specific until it breaks.

Comment: Is it successful for any of the files in your loop? Or does it raise an error on the first file it attempts every time?

Comment: I'm currently running each Excel file in the individual code that I know works to see if any of them error.

Comment: @SeeDerekEngineer each Excel file just ran fine through the code I wrote for single file. I just had to change the file name each time. FML. This will drive me insane.

Comment: for fname in FileList:

    df = pd.read_excel(fname, header=None, skipinitialspace=True,    skiprows=1) header = df.head(5).filter([0,2], axis=1)

Does this work?

Comment: posting a picture in the original post. Sorry, but it's just easier. This is the original code fore the single file and it works.

Comment: the for fname in FileLIst:..... is coming from a suggestion in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326179/running-code-through-a-folder-of-files-using-pandas/45326312?noredirect=1#comment77633642_45326312

Comment: Can you just write a list of all of the files?  

myFiles = ["File1.xlsx", "File2.xlsx", etc.]

Then do for fname in FileList:  df = pd.read_excel(fname, header=None, skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1) header = df.head(5).filter([0,2], axis=1)

Comment: well since this is done monthly with over 100 files, it would be more beneficially to not have to update the file name list every time. But wouldn't it be --- for fname in myFiles.....sorry just curious

Comment: Sorry, yes.  And this is just to prove it works in this way.  You can try then to make glob work after verifying this isnt the problem.

Comment: @SeeDerekEngineer doesn't have that error anymore lol. But now I have a keyerror in the worksheet = writer.sheets['Report Card'}

Comment: It ran, but only for the last file in the list. it didn't loop through all the files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150344/discussion-between-seederekengineer-and-sam-russo-palmer).